# assignment with df.iloc() returns nan

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})` and I would like to take some values and put them in another dataframe `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0]})`by creating new columns.

I created a new column 'B' `df2['B'] = df.iloc[0:2,0]` and everything was fine, but then i created another column C `df2['C'] = df.iloc[2:4,0]` and there were only NaN values. I don't know why and if I print `print(df.iloc[2:4])` everything is normal.

full code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0]})
df2['B'] = df.iloc[0:2,0]
df2['C'] = df.iloc[2:4,0]

print(df2)
print('\n',df.iloc[2:4])
```

output:

```
   A  B   C
0  0  1 NaN
1  0  2 NaN

    col
2    3
3    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignement `df2['C'] = df.iloc[2:4,0]` does not work as expected, because index is not the same. You can skip this using `.values` attributes.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0]})
df2['B'] = df.iloc[0:2,0]
df2['C'] = df.iloc[2:4,0].values

print(df2)
```